# Log4js permission error when installing something with npm

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, npm, log4js-node

I am learning web development and when I am installing tailwindcss using npm it throws this error:

```
log4js  <6.4.0
Severity: moderate
Incorrect Default Permissions in log4js - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-82v2-mx6x-wq7q
No fix available
node_modules/log4js
  ibmcloud-appid  *
  Depends on vulnerable versions of log4js
  node_modules/ibmcloud-appid

2 moderate severity vulnerabilities

Some issues need review, and may require choosing
a different dependency.
```

I have also tried uninstalling log4js using `npm uninstall log4js` and also deleting it from the computer using file explorer.
I also tried uninstalling node and re-installing node but that also didn't work.
I also tried installing log4js by using `npm install log4js` but that also didn't work

Important :-
I get this error when I use npm audit.